# How can I continuously redirect to a new page in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my register function in Rails project,I have registerd in my register page.Then I coded redirect to my register successfully page.How can I continue redirect to my login path automatically ?

```
def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)
  if (@user.save)
    flash[:success] = "register successfully"
    redirect_to register_success_path and return
  else
    render 'users/new'
  end
end

# so is that register_success_path action
def createSuccess
  Thread.new do
    sleep(3)
    redirect_to login_path
  end
end
```

Comment: Can't get you though, do you want to redirect to the login page after a user created successfully?

Comment: ya,and the first redirect to register_success_path ,then redirect to login_path in seconds

Comment: no need to write Thread for it, at last just redirect_it to login_path

Comment: But it will skip my register success page, I would like hold on this page seconds.then redirect to login page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this can be done by javascript as well,

remove the redirection from your createSuccess method and use below javascript in your view.

```
// redirect to google after 5 seconds
window.setTimeout(function() {
    window.location.href = 'localhost:3000/users/sign_in';
}, 5000);
```

you can also use ruby interpolation in `href` like `href = "#{login_path}"`

This will redirect to login page after 5 seconds

Comment: Could I set redirect timeout in my controller in rails as this js performance to solve my problem?

Comment: yes! just add sleep 5(seconds) before redirect_to but it's not feasible  as it won't render the view of createSuccess. you just need to remove thread. sleep(3) is correct but as I told it will not render the view of createSuccess , It will just wait and redirect to login_path

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways.
1. `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30"; url="http://example.com/" /> //content="30" is 30 seconds`
2. Answered by @Vishal.